# Round-trip XML -> XSD -> Class doesn't work?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xsd, deserialization

I have tried (and failed) do do the following.

1. Create a sample XML file.

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <test1>
     <test2>Test3</test2>
   </test1>`
2. Run it through Visual Studio 2010's `xsd` to generate an XSD file.

   `xsd test.xml`
3. Add the XSD file to a C# project in Visual Studio 2010. This adds the files:

   - `test.Designer.cs`
   - `test.xsc`
   - `test.xss`

   and shows up in the designer view as indicated below.

   [image]
4. Then I try to deserialize the file that started the whole thing:

`var reader = new FileStream("xml/test.xml", FileMode.Open);

    var serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(NewDataSet));
    var test = serializer.Deserialize(reader);`

and I get the error

[image]

The inner exception says `{"<test1 xmlns=''> was not expected."}`

What am I doing wrong? Or should I use `xsd` to generate the class also?

Comment: What's on line 2, character 2? Also, this seems to be a general XML parsing error, not specific to serialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that seems to be it:

`xsd test.xsd /c`

generates `test.cs`  an using this as the type, rather than `NewData` deserializes correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should open the file as bytes and then queue them into a MemoryStream.  Then you can deserialize from the MemoryStream.

The types/methods to look at are:

- [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx)
- [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx)

I can post a code sample if you need more direction.